# How to programatically swap spl tokens to sol

Tags: spl-token-program, spl

How to programatically swap spl tokens to sol, assuming there is liquidity pool (token/sol) created on flux beam. is there any standard interface to do it.

Comment: You may want to check with the flux beam team or GitHub to see if they provide a library for interacting with their program. I wasn't able to find anything with a quick search, but maybe you can reach out on their Discord or Telegram to get more info